# SQL SELECT multiple max values for a date

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-order-by

I am trying to get the latest record from a table by filtering a column with max, but it looks like I have multiple records for the same max date. I have added an ORDER BY at the end of the query and looks like I can actually retrieve the latest value since it has a correct order, but i don't know how.

Below you will find a descriptive image:
[image: Record that I want to obtain]

Also please find below the query that I am using:

```
SELECT *
  FROM item_forecast_detail 
  WHERE item_id = 177010 AND
        forecast_dt = (SELECT MAX(forecast_dt)
                         FROM item_forecast_detail
                         WHERE item_id = 177010) 
  ORDER BY forecast_dt DESC
```

Comment: So what exactly is the question?

Comment: How to get the latest/max value of multiple max results.

Answer (score 0):

Use `row_number()` window analytic function to order as desired, and `max(forecast_dt) over (order by forecast_dt desc)` to detect the latest date

```
SELECT *
  FROM
  (
   SELECT d.*, 
          row_number() over (order by ending_hour desc) as rn,
          max(forecast_dt) over (order by forecast_dt desc) as mx
     FROM item_forecast_detail d
    WHERE item_id=177010 
   )
  WHERE mx = forecast_dt
  ORDER BY rn
```

Comment: I understand that I can select the first row, but that's not I want, I would like it to be after comparing all records.

Comment: @Marcelo I think you mean having only the latest date, don't you ?

Comment: what I mean is that I want to get the latest value of all those max records without referencing the row. I would like to compare between them and get the highest. As an example of what I want is the ORDER BY...as you can see it can actually compare the values between them and get the latest even thought they are the same.

Answer (score 0):

One option is to apply another condition, e.g. fetch the latest `starting_hour`:

```
SQL> with item_forecast_Detail (item_id, forecast_dt, starting_hour) as
  2    (select 177010, date '2019-07-07', 21 from dual union all
  3     select 177010, date '2019-07-07', 18 from dual union all
  4     select 177010, date '2019-07-07', 15 from dual union all
  5     select 177010, date '2019-07-07', 12 from dual union all
  6     --
  7     select 123456, date '2019-02-17', 09 from dual
  8    )
  9  select *
 10  from item_forecast_Detail i
 11  where i.item_id = 177010
 12    and i.forecast_dt = (select max(i1.forecast_dt)
 13                         from item_forecast_detail i1
 14                         where i1.item_id = i.item_id
 15                        )
 16    and i.starting_hour = (select max(i2.starting_hour)
 17                           from item_forecast_detail i2
 18                           where i2.item_id = i.item_id
 19                          );

   ITEM_ID FORECAST_D STARTING_HOUR
---------- ---------- -------------
    177010 07.07.2019            21

SQL>
```

Another one is to sort them by using analytical function and apply it to the final query:

```
SQL> with item_forecast_Detail (item_id, forecast_dt, starting_hour) as
  2    (select 177010, date '2019-07-07', 21 from dual union all
  3     select 177010, date '2019-07-07', 18 from dual union all
  4     select 177010, date '2019-07-07', 15 from dual union all
  5     select 177010, date '2019-07-07', 12 from dual union all
  6     --
  7     select 123456, date '2019-02-17', 09 from dual
  8    ),
  9  sort as
 10    (select i.*,
 11            row_number() over (partition by item_id order by forecast_dt, starting_hour desc) rn
 12     from item_forecast_Detail i
 13    )
 14  select *
 15  from sort s
 16  where s.item_id = 177010
 17    and s.rn = 1;

   ITEM_ID FORECAST_D STARTING_HOUR         RN
---------- ---------- ------------- ----------
    177010 07.07.2019            21          1

SQL>
```

Comment: I thought about starting_hour, but isn't it possible without referencing the row or using another column? Can't I compare that value as ORDER BY does?

Comment: What would you compare those values by? Your query uses **only** `forecast_dt` and you got bunch of rows, all having the same `forecast_dt`. Which one is first? Which one is last? You can't tell. It is **pure luck** you got results sorted by "something" you find useful, but - without explicitly naming columns you're going to sort the result set, the final outcome is unknown. Oracle might sort them differently tomorrow or next week or next year. You **must** have something else to decide which row you want - `starting_hour` might be one choice.

Comment: I don't believe it is pure luck, it is too accurate to be luck. I have implemented starting_hour successfully but that's not the way I want to fix this issue. I thought I could max() between those values again or maybe compare them as ORDER BY does and get the latest.

Comment: Well, you'd rather believe. Once again: unless you properly use the `order by` clause, there's no guarantee that you'll get the correct result. In your case, `forecast_dt` is not enough. Furthermore, what "max" are you talking about? MAX applied to million rows whose `forecast_dt = 07-jul-2019` will return ... 07-jul-2019, what else could it return? They are all the same. You could have applied `where rownum = 1` to get only one row, but for the third time: there's no guarantee that you'll return desired value unless you properly use `order by`.

Answer (score 0):

You could try this with MySQL, SQLServer:

```sql
SELECT * FROM TABLE ORDER BY FORECAST_DT DESC LIMIT 1

SELECT TOP 1 * FROM Table ORDER BY FORECAST_DT DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use ROWNUM.

```
-- FETCH MAX FOR SINGLE item_id
WITH item_forecast_detail(item_id, forecast_dt, SOME_OTHER_COLS) AS (
SELECT 177010, DATE '2019-07-01','ANY VALUE - 1' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 177010, DATE '2019-07-01','ANY VALUE - 2' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 177010, DATE '2019-07-02','ANY VALUE - 4' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 177010, DATE '2019-07-02','ANY VALUE - 5' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 177010, DATE '2019-07-02','ANY VALUE - 6' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 177011, DATE '2019-07-01','ANY VALUE - 1' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 177011, DATE '2019-07-01','ANY VALUE - 1' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 177011, DATE '2019-06-30','ANY VALUE - 1' FROM DUAL
)
SELECT
    ITEM_ID,
    FORECAST_DT,
    SOME_OTHER_COLS
FROM
    (
        SELECT
            ITEM_ID,
            FORECAST_DT,
            SOME_OTHER_COLS,
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER(
                PARTITION BY ITEM_ID
                ORDER BY
                    FORECAST_DT DESC
            ) AS RN
        FROM
            ITEM_FORECAST_DETAIL
        WHERE
            ITEM_ID = 177010
    )
WHERE
    RN = 1
```

**OUTPUT**

[image]

```
-- FETCH MAX FOR MULTIPLE item_id
WITH item_forecast_detail(item_id, forecast_dt, SOME_OTHER_COLS) AS (
SELECT 177010, DATE '2019-07-01','ANY VALUE - 1' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 177010, DATE '2019-07-01','ANY VALUE - 2' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 177010, DATE '2019-07-02','ANY VALUE - 4' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 177010, DATE '2019-07-02','ANY VALUE - 5' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 177010, DATE '2019-07-02','ANY VALUE - 6' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 177011, DATE '2019-07-01','ANY VALUE - 1' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 177011, DATE '2019-07-01','ANY VALUE - 1' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 177011, DATE '2019-06-30','ANY VALUE - 1' FROM DUAL
)
SELECT
    ITEM_ID,
    FORECAST_DT,
    SOME_OTHER_COLS
FROM
    (
        SELECT
            ITEM_ID,
            FORECAST_DT,
            SOME_OTHER_COLS,
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER(
                PARTITION BY ITEM_ID
                ORDER BY
                    FORECAST_DT DESC
            ) AS RN
        FROM
            ITEM_FORECAST_DETAIL 
  --WHERE item_id = 177010
    )
WHERE
    RN = 1
```

**OUTPUT**

[image]

[DB<>FIDDLE DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=505d9d7993b87aa4400dac38bcbb12b1)

Cheers!!